# Questions about maximal torus of semisimple derivations of a nilpotent Lie algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

Let $\mathfrak{n}$ be a complex nilpotent Lie algebra of dimension $n$, and let $\mathfrak{t}$ be denote a *maximal torus of semisimple derivations* of $\mathfrak{n}$.

I would be very grateful if you could give me references, bibliography or counterexamples to study the following questions:

- Does there exist a basis $\mathcal{B}= \{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ of $\mathfrak{n}$ such that simultaneously diagonalizes $\mathfrak{t}$ **and** $\operatorname{ad}(X)$ is lower triangular matrix with respect to $\mathcal{B}$; for all $X \in \mathfrak{n}$?
- If $\operatorname{rank}(\mathfrak{n}) \geq 1$ (here, $\operatorname{rank}(\mathfrak{n}) = \operatorname{dim}(\mathfrak{t})$), does $\mathfrak{n}$ admit a semisimple derivation $D$ such that all its eigenvalues are non-negative real numbers?
- If $\operatorname{rank}(\mathfrak{n}) \geq 2$, does $\mathfrak{n}$ admit a semisimple derivation such that all its eigenvalues are positive real numbers?

Concerning the second and third question, It is easy to see that if a complex nilpotent Lie algebra is such that $\operatorname{rank}(\mathfrak{n})\geq 1$, then $\mathfrak{n}$ admits a semisimple derivation with integer eigenvalues.

Comment: In general, the pre-Einstein derivation (or also called Nikolayevsky Derivation by Tracy Payne) of a nilpotent Lie algebra with $\operatorname{rank}(\mathfrak{n})>0$ has not positive eigenvalues; we can consider a  $\operatorname{rank}$-1 nilpotent Lie Algebras with a null weight, for instance: $[X1,X2]=X4,[X1,X4]=X5,[X1,X5]=X6,[X1,X6]=X7,[X2,X3]=X6+X7,[X3,X4]=-X7$.

Comment: If $\mathfrak{n}$ is a real nilpotent Lie algebra admitting an inner product $<\cdot,\cdot>$ such that $\operatorname{Ric} = c\operatorname{Id} + D$, where $\operatorname{Ric}$ is the Ricci operator of the metric Lie algebra $(\mathfrak{n},<\cdot,\cdot>)$ and $D$ is a derivation of $\mathfrak{n}$, then the pre-Einstein derivation has positive eigenvalues, but I think that it is a very special sufficient condition to have a derivation of $\mathfrak{n}$ with positive eigenvalues.

Comment: Dear Prof. @DietrichBurde. Thank you so much for your interest in my question. About the Nikolayevsky derivation, I don't know if, in general, such derivation is positive semi-definite when the Lie algebra is nilpotent.

Comment: No, it is not always positive-semidefinite. Y. Nikolayevsky gives an example [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0612117.pdf) on page $9$ with negative eigenvalues. However, this example is $2$-step nilpotent, and we can find  of course a positive derivation for all $2$-step nilpotent Lie algebras.

Comment: Dear Prof. @DietrichBurde, I am very thankful to you for giving me the before example; I don't know it.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, this follows from Lie's Theorem applied to the solvable subalgebra $\mathfrak{t}\ltimes {\rm ad}(\mathfrak{n})$ of $\rm{Der}(\mathfrak{n})$. 
For the second question, every nilpotent Lie algebra admits a nonzero outer derivation $D$ with $D^2=0$ by a result of Togo, so with all eigenvalues equal to zero. 
For the third question, every Lie algebra admitting 
a derivation with only positive eigenvalues, is very special, namely is $\mathbb{N}$-graded, and has an *invertible* derivation. This is a serious restriction for a nilpotent Lie algebra. So I would think there could be a counterexample.

Comment: Dear Prof. @Dietrich Burde. For the first question, I think that it would be better to consider the complex solvable Lie algebra $\mathfrak{s}:=\mathfrak{t}\ltimes\operatorname{ad}\mathfrak{n}$; I'm thinking that it might be possible to obtain a refinement of Lie's theorem in this particular case, but I don't know if it is a well known result in the literature.

Comment: Concerning the second question, I have forgotten to say that it is important that the derivation be non trivial.

Comment: $\mathfrak{s}$ is solvable because $\operatorname{ad}(\mathfrak{n})$ is a nilpotent Lie algebra and $[\mathfrak{t},\operatorname{ad}(\mathfrak{n})] \subseteq \operatorname{ad}(\mathfrak{n})$.

In my second and third question, I apologize because I did not understand myself. In the definition of positive (semi-)definite transformation, such map is a Hermitian (symmetric) transformation with respect to a certain Hermitian (real) inner product.  Please allow me to reformulate my question.